# How to sort Listview columns when the header is clicked

Tags: vb.net, listview, sorting

I'm writing a homework planner and I have a ListView element.

I'm looking for a code snippet that allows me to arrange the columns in alphabetical order when I click on the column header. If it is already sorted in ascending order, then switch to descending and vice versa, then sort by the default/first one, i.e. "status" in the screenshot below.

I have googled and have found nothing I could use, can you help me?

[image: screenshot]

```
Private Sub ColumnClick(ByVal sender As Object, _
    ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.ColumnClickEventArgs) _
    Handles lvKalender.ColumnClick

    Select Case e.Column
        ' Nach Namen sortieren
        Case 0
            If lvKalender.Columns.Item(0).ListView.Sorting <> SortOrder.Descending Then
                lvKalender.Columns.Item(0).ListView.Sorting = SortOrder.Descending
            ElseIf lvKalender.Columns.Item(0).ListView.Sorting <> SortOrder.Ascending Then
                lvKalender.Columns.Item(0).ListView.Sorting = SortOrder.Ascending
            End If
        Case 1
            If (1).ListView.Sorting <> SortOrder.Descending Then
                lvKalender.Columns.Item(1).ListView.Sorting = SortOrder.Descending
            ElseIf lvKalender.Columns.Item(1).ListView.Sorting <> SortOrder.Ascending Then
                lvKalender.Columns.Item(1).ListView.Sorting = SortOrder.Ascending
            End If
        Case 2
            If lvKalender.Columns.Item(2).ListView.Sorting <> SortOrder.Descending Then
                lvKalender.Columns.Item(2).ListView.Sorting = SortOrder.Descending
            ElseIf lvKalender.Columns.Item(2).ListView.Sorting <> SortOrder.Ascending Then
                lvKalender.Columns.Item(2).ListView.Sorting = SortOrder.Ascending
            End If
        Case 3
            If lvKalender.Columns.Item(3).ListView.Sorting <> SortOrder.Descending Then
                lvKalender.Columns.Item(3).ListView.Sorting = SortOrder.Descending
            ElseIf lvKalender.Columns.Item(3).ListView.Sorting <> SortOrder.Ascending Then
                lvKalender.Columns.Item(3).ListView.Sorting = SortOrder.Ascending
            End If
        Case 4
            If lvKalender.Columns.Item(4).ListView.Sorting <> SortOrder.Descending Then
                lvKalender.Columns.Item(4).ListView.Sorting = SortOrder.Descending
            ElseIf lvKalender.Columns.Item(4).ListView.Sorting <> SortOrder.Ascending Then
                lvKalender.Columns.Item(4).ListView.Sorting = SortOrder.Ascending
            End If
        Case 5
            If lvKalender.Columns.Item(5).ListView.Sorting <> SortOrder.Descending Then
                lvKalender.Columns.Item(5).ListView.Sorting = SortOrder.Descending
            ElseIf lvKalender.Columns.Item(5).ListView.Sorting <> SortOrder.Ascending Then
                lvKalender.Columns.Item(5).ListView.Sorting = SortOrder.Ascending
            End If
        Case 6
            If lvKalender.Columns.Item(6).ListView.Sorting <> SortOrder.Descending Then
                lvKalender.Columns.Item(6).ListView.Sorting = SortOrder.Descending
            ElseIf lvKalender.Columns.Item(6).ListView.Sorting <> SortOrder.Ascending Then
                lvKalender.Columns.Item(6).ListView.Sorting = SortOrder.Ascending
            End If
    End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: you might want to translate that

Comment: Bitte schreiben Sie in Englisch! :)

Comment: sorry first tiem and i have translate it with googletranslator

Comment: Let me guess. You want to sort a ListView column depending on its content (dates, numbers, strings)?

Comment: no it are all strings once hour = stunde are an integer date is a string because i wrote the dates in mysql

Comment: yes i would sort all for itself on the alphabet and i know that i must normaly sort date and number it self but they are all ascii codes so i can sort it by the alphabet or not?? and i need a codesnip for these function

Comment: thanks for edit my english is very bad thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand your problem, you want to sort a column of Dates (and perhaps some values???) in a `ListView`.  The problem is that everything in a `ListView` is string/text.  Some subitems (cols) may **look** like dates, but that is just because that is how your brain translates/interprets them - they are actually strings.

The impact of this is that sorting text which has numbers rarely works out.  For example, `"90"` will always sort higher than `"300"` because `"9"` > `"3"`, and `"19.08.2014"` will sort higher than `"10.01.2019"`.  The value of *numerals* and *numbers* is not the same.

To sort by something other than a text, you need a `ListViewItemSorter`.  This one is for dates:

```
Friend Class ListViewItemDateComparer
    Implements IComparer
    Private col As Integer
    Private _sort As SortOrder = SortOrder.Ascending

    Public Sub New(column As Integer, sort As Windows.Forms.SortOrder)
        col = column
        _sort = sort
    End Sub

    Public Function Compare(x As Object,
                 y As Object) As Integer Implements System.Collections.IComparer.Compare
        Dim returnVal As Integer = -1

        ' parse LV contents back to DateTime value
        Dim dtX As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(CType(x, ListViewItem).SubItems(col).Text)
        Dim dtY As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(CType(y, ListViewItem).SubItems(col).Text)

        ' compare
        returnVal = DateTime.Compare(dtX, dtY)

        If _sort = SortOrder.Descending Then
            returnVal *= -1
        End If
        Return returnVal

    End Function
End Class
```

To use it:

```
Dim LVSorter = New ListViewItemDateComparer(COL_TO_SORT, Sort_Order)
myLV.ListViewItemSorter = LVSorter
```

`COL_TO_SORT` would be the column/subitem index you wish to sort which contains Dates.

`Sort_Order` would be the standard WinForms SortOrder (`SortOrder.Ascending` etc)

---

To compare other data types, `Decimal` for example, clone the `Comparer` and change the 3 lines doing the comparing:

```
' parse LV contents back to Decimal value
Dim dtX As Decimal = Decimal.Parse(CType(x, ListViewItem).SubItems(col).Text)
Dim dtY As Decimal = Decimal.Parse(CType(y, ListViewItem).SubItems(col).Text)

' compare
returnVal = Decimal.Compare(dtX, dtY)
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.listview.listviewitemsorter(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub ListViewProcess_ColumnClick(sender As Object, e As ColumnClickEventArgs) Handles ListViewProcess.ColumnClick
    sender.AutoResizeColumn(e.Column, ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.HeaderSize)
    If sender.Columns.Item(e.Column).ListView.Sorting <> SortOrder.Descending Then
        sender.Columns.Item(e.Column).ListView.Sorting = SortOrder.Descending
    ElseIf sender.Columns.Item(e.Column).ListView.Sorting <> SortOrder.Ascending Then
        sender.Columns.Item(e.Column).ListView.Sorting = SortOrder.Ascending
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub ColumnClick(ByVal sender As Object, _
    ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.ColumnClickEventArgs) _
    Handles lvKalender.ColumnClick

 If lvKalender.Columns.Item(e.Column).ListView.Sorting <> SortOrder.Descending Then
     lvKalender.Columns.Item(e.Column).ListView.Sorting = SortOrder.Descending
  ElseIf lvKalender.Columns.Item(e.Column).ListView.Sorting <> SortOrder.Ascending Then
     lvKalender.Columns.Item(e.Column).ListView.Sorting = SortOrder.Ascending
 End If

End Sub
```